# AS3 Tween dynamically created object along with other object

Tags: actionscript-3, tween

I'm trying to dynamically addChild a Sprite to an already tweened MovieClip (tweened on the Flash timeline).
Let's say ObjectA is the tweened object, I published it in my swc and linked it to my Actionscript project in Flash Builder.
I make an instance of ObjectA in my class, and then try to do the following:

var objectA:ObjectA = new ObjectA();
var objectB:ObjectB = new ObjectB();

objectA.addChild(objectB);
addChild(objectA);

Now, the problem is, objectB doesn't tween along with objectA. Is there any logical solution to this?

Thanks in advance,
Jennifer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example looks ok... now, are you actually tweening objectA and not a container or shape inside of objectA ? If this is the case, make the object inside a container and add objectB to it : `objectA.tweenedObject.addChild(objectB)`.